# How to validate dropdownlist control inside the gridview

Tags: asp.net

edit:

```
var dropDownControls = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> select option:selected');
var checkbox = $.......checkbox ..... 
  for(index = 0; index < dropDownControls.length; index++)
  {
      if (checkbox.checked) //my code gets exaclty what checkbox i checked
      {
      if(dropDownControls[index].selectedIndex == 0)
      {
          flag = false;
          break;
      }
      }
  }
```

the above code works

i have my button outside the gridivew and i am trying to validate the dropdownlist which is inside the gridivew.

```
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btn_Click"  CausesValidation="true"/>


<asp:GridView ID="GVInputMapping" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
                             EnableModelValidation="True" onrowdatabound="GVInputMapping_RowDataBound">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox id="checkbox1" runat="server"/>
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddldetail">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select me</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="1">abc</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="2">GHt</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredDDL" runat="server" 
              ControlToValidate="ddldetail" ErrorMessage="Please select" InitialValue="Select me"  Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
credit goes to ahaliav fox

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10566599/how-to-control-asp-net-validator-controls-client-side-validation


 gridview:

    <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"  OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="FirstName"
                    SortExpression="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" ControlStyle-Width="250px" HeaderText="LastName"
                    SortExpression="LastName" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkbox1" runat="server" />
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="drpPaymentMethod" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="-1">----</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="0">Month</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">At End</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">At Travel</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfv" InitialValue="-1" ControlToValidate="drpPaymentMethod" Enabled="false" Display="Static" runat="server" ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Value">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Value" runat="server" Width="58px" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

CS:

    protected void gv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                CheckBox checkbox1 = e.Row.FindControl("checkbox1") as CheckBox;
                RequiredFieldValidator rfv = e.Row.FindControl("rfv") as RequiredFieldValidator;
                DropDownList drpPaymentMethod = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("drpPaymentMethod");
                // you can just pass "this" instead of "myDiv.ClientID" and get the ID from the DOM element
                checkbox1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UpdateValidator('" + checkbox1.ClientID + "','" + drpPaymentMethod.ClientID + "','" + rfv.ClientID + "');");
                if (!checkbox1.Checked)
                    drpPaymentMethod.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }

javascript:

    function UpdateValidator(chkID, drpID, validatorid) {
            //enabling the validator only if the checkbox is checked
            var enableValidator = $("#" + chkID).is(":checked");

            if (enableValidator)
                $('#' + drpID).removeAttr('disabled');
            else
                $('#' + drpID).attr('disabled', 'disabled');

            var vv = $('#' + validatorid).val();

            ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById(validatorid), enableValidator);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `RequiredFieldValidator`'s [`InitialValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.initialvalue.aspx) to **0** instead of *"Select me"* since the item that is selected by default has a value of 0

```
<asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="0">Select me</asp:ListItem>
```

Apart from that it should work fine.

**Edit**: Your comments revealed that you use jQuery to enable a CheckBox that fixes the `DropDownList` selection. The user should have selected something now. So your requirement actualy is that no the validator should be active. So disable all Validators initially(`Enabled="false"`).

Since you're handling the checkbox click on clientside anyway, i would recommend to enable the validator if it's checked and disable it when it's unchecked. You can use the (Mini-)[Validation-Client-Side API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside) especially the `ValidatorEnable(val, enable)` function. You only need a reference to the validator. But that should not a problem for you.

Comment: Tim, my button is outside the gridview control and i have tried what you have suggest but the problem is that its validating all the rows instead of just one row (the one i checked the checkbox)

Comment: You haven't mentioned this requirement and the CheckBox at all. Then you need to enable the Validators on [CheckBox-CheckedChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checkedchanged.aspx) or/and in `RowDataBound` of the GridView initially.

Comment: sorry about that i missed the checkbox and i have updated my question, again i am still not sure how the validation will work since `my submit button is outside the gridview`

Comment: @issoa: As i've said above. Validators will not fire when they are disabled. So you need to set them all `Enabled="false"` initially. Then you can enable them on CheckBox-CheckedChanged event. Or, if it depends on a value in the datatabase, set the enabled/disabled state from `RowDataBound`. It's also possible to enable them with javascript without postback(`ValidatorEnable`-function). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

Comment: I understand your suggestion and currently my checkbox is enabled and dropdownlist is disabled using the jquery when the user is checked on the checkbox i enabled the dropdownlist and user have choice to select from dropdownlist or without selecting use can click on submit button for validation dont want to use server side code and do you have any other suggestions code, i will paste the javascript code what i have done.

Comment: @issoa: Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use a customValidator and use client side scripts to validate. Then use a validation summary to display the error or the requirement